# H2 - Why GROUP_CONCAT rejects rows with NULL values?

Tags: java, null, field, h2, group-concat

Run this script:

```
drop table if exists foo cascade;
create table foo(
       id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
       start date NOT NULL,
       end date
);

insert into foo(start,end) values('2007-01-01', '2007-12-31');
insert into foo(start,end) values('2007-01-01', NULL);

SELECT
     COUNT(*) nb,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
             id || '-' || start || '-' || end
             SEPARATOR CHAR(10)
      ) final
FROM
     foo;
```

Why does H2 returns this

```
-------------------------------
|NB |  FINAL                  |
-------------------------------
|2  | 1-2007-01-01-2007-12-31 |
-------------------------------
```

instead of

```
-------------------------------
|NB |  FINAL                  |
-------------------------------
|2  | 1-2007-01-01-2007-12-31 |
|   | 2-2007-01-01-NULL       |
-------------------------------
```

?

How should I change my query for having expected result ?

Comment: Why should `NB` have the value 2 on the first row of your desired result? Also, what would make the rows separate rows? You'll need something to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I expect one row only. The first column with 2 and the second column with one string containing a CHAR(10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For H2, the operator `||` by default returns `NULL` if one operators is `NULL`. This behavior is the same as in many other database, including PostgreSQL.

However, MySQL doesn't work like that. H2 supports a [compatibility mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) for MySQL where the behavior is different. Please note H2 is still not 100% compatible with MySQL when using the MySQL mode, but this aspect is changed.

If you run the statements above with the MySQL mode (`set mode mysql` or append `;mode=mysql` in the database URL) then the result is:

```
2   1-2007-01-01-2007-12-31
    2-2007-01-01-
```

so that `NULL` is converted to an empty string.

Probably even better is to not rely on the MySQL mode, but use `CONCAT` instead of `||`. This is the more standard way, as it should work with other databases as well:

```
concat(id, '-', start, '-', end)
```